# how to catch errors globally in react app

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, try-catch

I have the following two files:

```
//index.js

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and

```
// App.js
setTimeout(() => { throw new Error('An error')}, 3000)

class App extends Component {
  render() {return (<div>Hello</div>)}
}
```

I want to catch this error outside of the `App.js` file, potentially in `index.js`. I tried using `ErrorBoundries` (https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html), but clearly that wouldnt catch errors outside the component lifecycle.

Someone suggested me to use `window.onerror` error handler. My concern with this approach is that even if one of the external libraries thrown an error, this would get triggered. Any comments on that?

Comment: so.. don't `throw` ? just call a function that throws. problem solved. `throw()`

Comment: sorry ... dont quite understand ... can you please show me some code

Comment: @MeetZaveri did you read the question??

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to catch errors globally that do not include 3rd party stuff, then don't `throw` your own errors, just use a function and throw there

Using your exact code:

```
// utils.js
export default {
  throw: err => { throw new Error(err) }
}

// App.js
import utils from 'utils'

setTimeout(() => { utils.throw('An error') }, 3000)

class App extends Component {
  render() {return (<div>Hello</div>)}
}
```

Comment: I dont quite want to touch App.js .
The situation is that I have been handed over tons of code that can throw errors anywhere at will. I just want to somehow have a global-error-handler that would catch them all, log the to our server, and show a graceful message to the user

Comment: it's 100% impossible to do what you want and also exclude errors that are not generated from *your* code. once it hits the runtime the difference between *your* code and 3rd party code is lost

Comment: thanks @azium . that may be well the case. Just that in languages like Java, just putting a try/catch block globally would have been sufficient. thanks for your efforts though

Comment: that's terrible practice though... you shouldn't ever do that in java or javascript

Comment: showing a screen full or errors or a crashed App is perhaps worst :)